# Add text to outlook task in RTF-format

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to add extra information to an Outlook-task using RTF-formatted strings.
I got the following code:

```
With objTask
    .Body = objJournal.Body + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + .Body
    .Body = "Categories:" + vbTab + objJournal.Categories + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + .Body
    .Body = "Duration:" + vbTab + CStr(objJournal.Duration) + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + .Body
    .Body = "End:" + vbTab + vbTab + Format(objJournal.Start, "ddd yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") + vbCrLf + .Body
    .Body = "Start:" + vbTab + vbTab + Format(objJournal.End, "ddd yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") + vbCrLf + .Body
    .Body = "Entry Type:" + vbTab + objJournal.Type + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + .Body
    .Body = "Subject:" + vbTab + vbTab + objJournal.Subject + vbCrLf + .Body
End With
```

I know that you can use .RTFBody instead to preserve formatting but can somebody help me how to convert the strings I want to add to the RTF-format ?

Kind regards,

Wamors

Answer (score 0):

Manually create an RTF file, open nit in Notepad, and use the fild contents as your own template. Keep in mind that setting RTFBody in VBA might not work - it only works using late binding.

Also, do not use the Body property as an intermediary variable - setting an retrieving message body is expensive. Use a dedicated variable and set the Body property only once when you are done.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry for your response. I will take notice of your remarks